# Introduce delay in ajax query javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a search field. I would like to sendout the search query after a certain delay (eg 2000 ms)

Here is relevant angularjs code that I have managed to produce.

But I am certain **there must be a better pattern to do this...**

```
function SearchController($scope, $http, $timeout){ 

    var update_results = function(originalWord){
        if (originalWord == $scope.search_term){
            $http.get("/search/"+ $scope.search_term).success(function(data){
                $scope.search_results = data;
            });
        }
    };
    $scope.search = function(){
        var originalWord = $scope.search_term.replace("xxxx", "xxxx"); //UGLY HACK TO CLONE A STRING
        $timeout(function(){
            update_results(originalWord);
        }, 2000);
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you used $timeout is great.
I've seen lots of angularJS codes and all of them use the same mechanism to fire up an event after a certain amount of time.